# How to create add colors to listview in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a listview in android and want to alternate colors to the listview?

My code:

```
String listview_array[] = { "1. Test1", "2. Test2" }

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listview_header_row, listview_array));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom Adapter  for this

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    //Do assigning here Then change color

    if ((position%2)==0) {
      rowView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.first);
    } else {
      rowView.setImageResource(R.color.second);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

For more about custom Adapter See [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)

Answer (score 0):

the way u  set array content listview_array[] in the list view 
you can make array of colors and put it on background of listview .
use array position for list color postion.
this may solve ur problem :)

Comment: just make an array of colors hashcode or R.string.label (put hashcode in string file) u want as background of rows and set it the way u set the names ... adapters are used to put data in listview.. u can put colors aswell..

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90